Slovak "Long term residence EU" permit can stay in **any** EU country?
I hold a 10 year EU long-term residence permit (issued in Slovakia).
I want to move to (and buy a house, and live in) France.
Despite explaining my status, I have been recommended by a visa expert to begin the entire French residency permit from the very beginning, as a foreigner (NZ national).
I believe that with my permit, I can travel and live and work anywhere in the EU, buy a house, reside there, and (if necessary) do the paperwork to become a French national at some later time.
Who is right:

I can move and live there for the next ~8 years, and take my time about becoming a citizen/etc
My advisor is right: I must initiate a French Carte de Sejour before I enter the country, despite my EU permit


So.... A visa expert or you.... Tough question.... What's your basis? Residency is based on country, Slovakia has no say as to who's allowed to live in France.

@littleadv my (EU) permit allows live and work in any EU member state for the duration of that permit. That seems clear. Why is France considered a special case?

No, you are incorrect, your long term EU residence permit only allows you to live in the country that issued it, the only special right is that you can apply to transfer it to another participating EU country, it is not automatic. Also note that with this permit, you are still subject to the 90-180 rule in Schengen countries that are not the country that issued the permit.

@Dr.Snoopy thanks - but I have seen no info on this anywhere. If it is true, why then apply for a carte de sejour from the beginning, if I can simply 'convert' it to the French equivalent?

Maybe neither of you is right, and/or you should get a 2nd opinion from another expert. To get an EU long-term resident card for France you need to have  resided there for 5 years. You can check if you need a LTV for France here

@DefenestrationDay Where did you get the (wrong) information you have about EU LTR? Maybe you get confused with some new proposals (not yet in law). Here is an example for Netherlands: https://ind.nl/en/residence-permits/long-term-eu-residency/coming-to-the-netherlands-as-a-long-term-eu-resident

You are definitely wrong but the advice you got (and Mark's answer) also contain inaccuracies that suggest they are not familiar with French law and practices.
In general, in the EU, residence for more than 3 months is a national matter, you will need a French titre de séjour (residence document) to reside in France for a few years. There is simply no EU-wide residence permit and there is no other document or EU permit of any kind that would allow third-country (non-EU) citizens to reside in France.
This means that you will indeed need to apply for a French residence permit from the beginning. In your case, that would presumably be a carte de séjour visiteur unless you found a job or want to create a business. Where the advice you received goes wrong is that you may not apply for that permit from outside France but only immediately after moving. A proof of address (justificatif de domicile) will be required for your application.
What the EU long-term residence permit and a few other documents like the EU Blue card get you is the right to move to France to apply for the relevant carte de séjour directly. Otherwise, you would first need to apply for a visa (visa long séjour) from Slovakia before moving and following the rest of the procedure. Such a visa is required even for people who do not require visas for short stays in the Schengen area (like NZ citizens) or hold a regular (i.e. not “long term”) residence permit from another EU country.
There are ways around this requirement for hardship, if you have family in France, etc. but unlike Germany or the Netherlands (which allow NZ citizens to skip the visa step), France does not make an exception based on citizenship (except possibly for Algerian citizens, who fall under a completely different system).
In summary, the actual process looks like this:

Look up the requirements, start preparing the documents you need, you won't have much time to sort it out after moving.
Move to France.
Apply for the carte de séjour within three months of arriving in France, including a copy of your EU long-term residence permit instead of the visa that would otherwise be required.



I believe that with my permit, I can travel and live and work anywhere in the EU, buy a house, reside there, and (if necessary) do the paperwork to become a French national at some later time.

From the first link, one part of your question is answered:

An EU long-term residence permit allows you to settle in almost all other EU Member States (except Ireland and Denmark) under less strict conditions.

Article 15 (1) of Directive - 2003/109 allows you to apply for a French residence permit after arrival, but no later than 3 months.


I have been recommended by a visa expert to begin the entire French residency permit from the very beginning, as a foreigner (NZ national).

You must apply for a new residence permit for France, so as such the 'the very beginning' portion is correct.
The EU long-term residence permit for Slovakia will remain valid until you qualify for an EU long-term residence permit in France.
Until then should, if for whatever reason, you are asked to leave, you may resume your residence in Slovakia. (Article 22 (2) of Directive - 2003/109)

I can move and live there for the next ~8 years, and take my time about becoming a citizen/etc

Assuming you apply for a French residence permit (at the latest) within the first 3 months, yes.

My advisor is right: I must initiate a French Carte de Sejour before I enter the country, despite my EU permit.

You can apply for the residence permit before arrival, but are not required to do so.
Your visa expert recommended this (based on your wording above), not that you must.
Overall I would say your advisor is right.


Article 15 Conditions for residence in a second Member State

As soon as possible and no later than three months after entering the territory of the second Member State, the long-term resident shall apply to the competent authorities of that Member State for a residence permit.

Member States may accept that the long-term resident submits the application for a residence permit to the competent authorities of the second Member State while still residing in the territory of the first Member State.

Member States may require the persons concerned to provide evidence that they have:
(a) stable and regular resources which are sufficient to maintain themselves and the members of their families, without recourse to the social assistance of the Member State concerned. For each of the categories referred to in Article 14(2), Member States shall evaluate these resources by reference to their nature and regularity and may take into account the level of minimum wages and pensions;
(b) sickness insurance covering all risks in the second Member State normally covered for its own nationals in the Member State concerned.

...
Article 22 Withdrawal of residence permit and obligation to readmit

If the second Member State adopts one of the measures referred to in paragraph 1, the first Member State shall immediately readmit without formalities the long-term resident and his/her family members. The second Member State shall notify the first Member State of its decision.



Sources:

BAMF - Bundesamt für Migration und Flüchtlinge - Mobility with an EU long-term residence permit
Directive - 2003/109 - EN - EUR-Lex


You cannot apply for a French residence permit abroad, period. A proof of address (justificatif de domicile) will be required.
